# Why we need a list as property in the entity classes of a one to many relationship in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

[image]

```
                                   EER Diagram
```

My question is that why we need to have a list in the one to many relationship ,because for an example if you have a relationship of one to many between Instructor and Course classes[one instructor can teach many courses,but one course has only one instructor] why we need to have a list of courses in instructor class.I mean I already saved both instructor and course data to mysql database with the aid of the foreign key in course class.So why still we need that property of list ?

**Course model class the property of private Instructor instructorId with the annotations of @ManyToOne,@JoinColoumn**

***Please note that instructorDetail class is not related to this question.**

Comment: You don't. It's perfectly valid to have a unidirectional ManyToOne association. But it can be quite handy to have a OneToMany association: isn't it quite nice to be able to get the courses of a teacher using `teacher.getCourses()` rather than to have to write and execute a query?

Comment: @JBNizet thank you very much my guess was the same thank you very much for helping me to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to include that list, and it wouldn't change the database structure under the hood. Having that list is only for comfort, enabling you to execute queries using the courses list of an instructor.